# How can I copy the records of the file “/etc/bashrc” that have the “TMOUT” string except those containing the “read-only” string, to the file?

Tags: text-processing

my question is about centos file copy

How can I copy the records of the file “/etc/bashrc” that have the “TMOUT” string except those containing the “read-only” string, to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep 'TMOUT' /etc/bashrc | grep -v 'read-only' >output
```

This first extracts all lines from `/etc/bashrc` that contains the string `TMOUT`.  The second `grep` removes all of those lines that *also* contain the string `read-only`.  The output is saved to the file `output`.

Answer (score 0):

With just one command:

```
awk '/TMOUT/ && !/read-only/' < /etc/bashrc > output
```

Or:

```
sed '/TMOUT/!d; /read-only/d' < /etc/bashrc > output
```

(`d`elete the lines that don't (`!`) contain `TMOUT` and those that contain `read-only`).

Those also have the advantage of not clobbering the `output` file if `/etc/bashrc` can't be opened.